# PHP MySQL query with %s and %d

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS test FROM %s WHERE id = %d AND tmp_mail <> ''
```

What are `%s` and `%d` for?

Comment: Using sprintf() is marginally better than string concatenation. For a more robust approach though, you should look at _Prepared Statements_

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Those are format symbols used e.g. by `sprintf()`. Example:

```
<?php
 $sql_template = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS test FROM %s WHERE id = %d AND tmp_mail <> ''";
 $sql_real = sprintf($sql_template, 'sometable', 12345);
 echo $sql_real;
?>
```

Output:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS test FROM sometable WHERE id = 12345 AND tmp_mail <> ''
```

Answer (score 7):

That are probably [format symbols](http://docs.php.net/sprintf) for *string* and *decimal integer*.